# horizontal LinearLayout with 3 TextViews of which the 2nd has to stay centered

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my first time asking a Question myself, so please be patient :-).
I have a horizontal LinearLayout in which I have 3 TextViews.
The 2nd is only a Arrow (UTF-8 Character), which is supposed to be exactly centered.
The TextViews are 1 line only and if it does not fit, it should simply be cut off.
I tried to use weights on the 1st and 3rd TextView but if the 1stTextView contains too much text, the arrow is still slightly shifted to the right instead of staying centered (which I expected the weights to ensure).
Here is what I tried so far:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width"wrap_content"
        android:layout_height"wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width"wrap_content"
        android:layout_height"wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="→"/>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width"wrap_content"
        android:layout_height"wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Text of the 1st and 3rd TextView is set programmatically during runtime.
If the text is short enough everything is fine.
If the text in the 1st TextView is too long, it is cut (as intented!), but still the 2nd (Arrow-)TextView is nontheless shifted to the right to a certain degree.
I want the arrow to stay exactly centered and the text on the left and right to be cut if necessary.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: But why are you using LinearLayout in the first place?  This is a typical FramLayout with your arrow being centred and textviews aligned parent left and parent right.

Comment: Better though, if you use a RelativeLayout

Comment: Could you please give an example explaining how to use FrameLayout for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how I would do it (works), by using a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArrow"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="?"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtArrow"
        android:text="Left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtArrow"
        android:text="Right"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I first declared the **central** TextView.
Then I added the other two **around it**.

Comment: Thats the thing I did not realise I can do: At first declare the center. Thanks, it works!

Comment: It's because this is the **reference** View. Then, the other two can refer to it by id and align **relatively** to it.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! I do understand what you say ;-). I thought about using a RelativeLayout but I didnt really understand how to fill the whole width. layout_centerVertical is what I was not realising to be possible. I guess I learned something about how to use RelativeLayouts in general..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Give your all `TextView` width `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="→"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This results in the arrow taking all the space and the 1st and 3rd TextView not being shown at all. I dont know why, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this work....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"

        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="→"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Linear layout weight =3 and distribute this weight equally in all these three TextView .

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="7"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"

        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="→"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```